# How to run a file on successful htaccess rewrite/redirect?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to run a file/script (that sends me an email notification) when a file matches a rewrite/redirect pattern in htaccess.

Can I do it without rewriting to the script file itself then that file performs a simple redirect?

Eg.

```
RewriteRule ^location/of/old/script/(.*) /my/new/location/$1
Call /notify.php?file=$1
```

Comment: Are you able to make even small modifications to `notify.php`? If so, you could use `php_value auto_prepend_file notify.php` inside a `<LocationMatch>` and then call `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` inside `notify.php` instead of `file=$1`.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I haven't even written `notify.php` yet so it can have whatever is required to get it working. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mod_rewrite can't call external programs outside of the `RewriteMap`'s `prg` map type, but that's not going to help you unless you write a script to specifically handle rewrite map calls. You're best bet is to rewrite to `notify.php`, and from there, load the `/my/new/location/` file:

```
RewriteRule ^location/of/old/script/(.*)$ /notify.php?file=$1 [L]
```

Then in the `notify.php` script:

```
readfile(_$GET['file']);
```

Comment: I want to avoid this method, but it seems like the only option. :(